# How to get phone memory in Ubuntu Terminal?

Tags: photorec

I have a Samsung smartphone, connected via USB cable with my HP laptop . I want to recover some of my deleted photos with **photorec** command form **terminal**. But while I give command `$ cd /media/hp`, I cannot see my phone memory, but it shows the **pen drive**. I want to know that how can I get my phone memory by **command line**.